# Pytest example code test fails and unsure what the results indicate is the source/nature of the error

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm following the Pycharm documentation for using Pytest (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html).
I enter the example code and follow the instructions to execute an example test, which should pass. It doesn't and I am not sure exactly what the nature or source of the error is?

Here is the code for the test:

```
from Car import Car


def test_car_brake():
    car = Car(50)
    car.brake()
    assert car.speed == 45
```

Here is my failed test results with errors:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... 
test_Car_pytest.py:None (test_Car_pytest.py)
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/kirbyd/PycharmProjects/Computational_Methods_Course/Assignments/Final/test_Car_pytest.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../../.conda/envs/Computational_Methods_Course/New_Interpreter_Place/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:578: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.fspath, mode=importmode)
../../../../.conda/envs/Computational_Methods_Course/New_Interpreter_Place/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:524: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
../../../../.conda/envs/Computational_Methods_Course/New_Interpreter_Place/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1030: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1007: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:680: in _load_unlocked
    ???
../../../../.conda/envs/Computational_Methods_Course/New_Interpreter_Place/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:170: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
test_Car_pytest.py:1: in <module>
    from Car import Car
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Car'


collected 0 items / 1 error

=============================== 1 error in 0.13s ===============================
ERROR: not found: /Users/kirbyd/PycharmProjects/Computational_Methods_Course/Assignments/Final/test_Car_pytest.py::test_car_brake
(no name '/Users/kirbyd/PycharmProjects/Computational_Methods_Course/Assignments/Final/test_Car_pytest.py::test_car_brake' in any of [<Module test_Car_pytest.py>])


Process finished with exit code 4
```

I see there's "no module named Car" but they have that in their code and it is supposed to work fine. What's going wrong here?

Comment: it looks like Car doesen't exist. Are you sure you have a Car.py?

Comment: The tutorial creates a file called Car.py containing a class `Car`.  This script is testing that class.  Did you create that file?  Is this test script in the same directory as Car.py?

Comment: Yes, I have created the Car.py file as it shows here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html

Comment: And I also have both files in the same directory